# Oracle behavior multiple calls for the same procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

First sorry for my bad english but go to the problem, I have multiple calls for the same procedure and I would like to know when working with multiple calls to the same procedure Oracle uses one instance for each call or static mode to work, running a call at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about variables in a SP, when making multiple calls, they are not shared. Oracle will allocate space for the instance variables separately in PGA each time the SP is invoked.

Comment: I have the following situations, about multiple calls of the same procedure:

- It is called by WindowsServices;
- It is called by a WebPage; and
- It is called by a scheduled job.

For example, I want to know if, when these multiple calls happens, the Oracle works simutaneously to all these calls, or the Oracle works with queue.

Comment: @RafaelAdonis Yes, Oracle is definitely capable of running the same procedure multiple times concurrently.  There is no locking on procedure calls.  There may be locks caused by work inside the procedure, for example if the procedure updates the same row each time.  If you're worried about blockers, you can find them with `select * from gv$session where final_blocking_session is not null;`.

Comment: @jonearles Tks for answer!